# Basic Rails design for belongs_to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are many questions like this but I can't find one that seems to answer the specific question - apologies if this is a repeat.

I have a model, let's call it a Shark, with a very simple definition (here, annotated:)

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: sharks
#
#  id                :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at        :datetime        not null
#  updated_at        :datetime        not null
#  origination_entry :integer
#

class Shark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :originator, class_name: "Shark", foreign_key:"id"
  attr_accessible :origination_entry
end
```

Specifically, the "origination_entry" column in the database should be a **foreign key** back to *the same table*, Sharks. The idea is that every entry might have either `null` in that relation, or else it will point to another `Shark` object that was the 'originator' of this `Shark`. (By 'originator', I am referring to a prior instance of this `Shark` - trust me, this makes sense with more background.)

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

```
irb(main):001:0> shark1 = Shark.new(idnumber:"foo")
=> #<Shark id: nil, idnumber: "foo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, origination_entry: nil>
irb(main):002:0> shark1.save()
=> true
irb(main):003:0> 
irb(main):004:0* shark2 = Shark.new(idnumber:"foo", origination_entry:shark1.id)=> #<Shark id: nil, idnumber: "foo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, origination_entry: 3>
irb(main):005:0> shark2.save()
=> true
irb(main):006:0> shark2
=> #<Shark id: 4, idnumber: "foo", created_at: "2012-06-26 22:35:19", updated_at: "2012-06-26 22:35:19", origination_entry: 3>
irb(main):007:0> shark2.originator
=> nil
```

(I snipped out some SQL queries, let me know if they would be helpful.)

Why is it returning `nil`? How can I instead get it to return `shark1`'s object?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, something I tried to remove from the example code but forgot in a few places. There are actually five or six other fields in the table, but they are not relevant. The confusingly named 'idnumber' is in fact a string (and neither a number nor a unique ID) - I didn't choose the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It works for me

```
class Shark < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :originator, class_name: "Shark", foreign_key:"origination_entry"
   attr_accessible :origination_entry
end
```

[This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) docs are very useful for AR associations and options ;)

Comment: Very nearly accurate, and you'll get the 'accept' for giving me the link (thanks!).

I'll edit in the working code (it's my first time editing on SO, might get it wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
class Shark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : creator, class_name: "Shark", foreign_key:"shark_id"
  attr_accessible :origination_entry
end
```

Comment: I thought that might have been it, but sadly no. Close though! Thanks. Caulfield seems to have it right (or nearly - I submitted an edit.)